# Performance and readability of RegEx using positive look ahead

Tags: c#, regex

I am validating following strings with regular expressions in C#:

> [/1/2/]
>   [/1/2/];[/3/4/5/]
>   [/1/22/333/];[/1/];[/9999/]

Basically it's one or more group of square brackets separated by semi-colon (but not at the end). Each group consists out of one or more numbers seperated by slashes. There are no other characters allowed.

These are two alternatives:

```regex
^(\[\/(\d+\/)+\](;(?=\[)|$))+$

^(\[\/(\d+\/)+\];)*(\[\/(\d+\/)+\])$
```

The first version uses a positive look ahead and the second version duplicates part of the pattern.

Both RegEx-es seem to be ok, do what they should and aren't very nice to read. ;)

Does anybody have an idea for a better, faster and more easy to read solution? When I was playing around in [regex101](https://regex101.com/#) I realized that the second version uses more steps, why?

At the same time I realized that it would be nice to count the steps used in a C#-RegEx. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How can a RegEx be easy to read? :)

Comment: Here is a regex that is easy to read: `\d+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 1 regex to validate all these strings:

```
^\[/(\d+/)+\](?:;\[/(\d+/)+\])*$
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5C%5B%2F(%5Cd%2B%2F)%2B%5C%5D(%3F%3A%3B%5C%5B%2F(%5Cd%2B%2F)%2B%5C%5D)*%5Cr%3F%24&i=%5B%2F1%2F2%2F%5D%0D%0A%5B%2F1%2F2%2F%5D%3B%5B%2F3%2F4%2F5%2F%5D%0D%0A%5B%2F1%2F22%2F333%2F%5D%3B%5B%2F1%2F%5D%3B%5B%2F9999%2F%5D&o=m)

To make it easier to read, use a VERBOSE flag (inline `(?x)` or `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`):

```
var rx = @"(?x)^               # Start of string
           \[/             # Literal `[/`
           (\d+/)+         # 1 or more sequences of 1 or more digits followed by `/`
           \]              # Closing `]`
           (?:             # A non-capturing group start
             ;             # a semi-colon delimiter
              \[/(\d+/)+\] # Same as the first part of the regex
           )*              # 0 or more occurrences
           $               # End of string
";
```

To test a .NET regex performance (not the number of steps), you can use a [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/) service. With the 3 sample strings above, my regex shows 217K iterations per second speed, which is more than either of your regexps.

Comment: I tested the regex on my machine and all the 3 strings in your post match. There is no way to oversimplify your regex, because otherwise validation won't work correctly (as you have already seen with Dan's regex).

Comment: If you don't need the captures of the groups you can speed up your regex by enabling explicit capture: `(?n)^\[/(\d+/)+\](;\[/(\d+/)+\])*$`

Comment: If the captured groups are not used, I'd just remove the capturing groups at all, and keep just the non-capturing one used for grouping. No need for explicit capture feature here.

Comment: Ähm - How do you perform the repetition without a group? `(\d+/)+`

Comment: Turn them into non-capturing of course: `^\[/(?:\d+/)+\](?:;\[/(?:\d+/)+\])*$`.

Comment: Oh - yes, you're right - but you need `?:` three times instead of `(?n)` only once or specify the parameter to the regex ctor. I'm pretty sure that the captures are not used in that case.

Comment: The problem with `(?n)` is that it is not a "portable" solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing particularly wrong with the two options you suggest.  They are not that complicated as regexes go, and they should be understandable enough, as long as you put an appropriate comment in your code.

In general, I think it is preferable to avoid look-arounds, unless they are necessary or greatly simplify the regex--they make it harder to figure out what is going on, since they add a non-linear element to the logic.

The relative performance of regexes this simple is not something to worry about, unless you are performing a huge number of operations or discover a performance problem with your code.  Still, understanding the relative performance of different patterns may be instructive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the explanations. But I'm afraid it doesn't work in all cases. This one should work too: `;[/1/2/];[/1/2/]`

Comment: @PzYon, oops, good catch.  In that case I don't have any simpler suggestion!